# Adding attributes to large datasets using command line tools

Tags: attributes, command, multiple-columns

I have an extremely large dataset (approx. 150 MB; 500 targets; 700,000+ attributes). I need to add one attribute to the end of each file.
The date file that I am working with has the following structure:

```
@relation 'filename'
@attribute "place" string
@attribute "institution" string
@attribute "food" string
@attribute "book" string

@data
3.8,6,0,0,church
86.3,0,63.1,0,man
0,0,0,37,woman
```

I need to add one attribute of information to each of the rows following @data.
However, due to its sheer number of attributes, I cannot open and modify the data in a text editor.
The attribute that I need to include I have in a separate tab separated file that has the following structure:

```
church  1
man 1
woman   0
```

The desired result would have the data set look like this:

```
@relation 'filename'
@attribute "place" string
@attribute "institution" string
@attribute "food" string
@attribute "book" string

@data
3.8,6,0,0,church,1
86.3,0,63.1,0,man,1
0,0,0,37,woman,0
```

Where the command would look to match the end of each line after @data with each line of the second file and if it is a match add the corresponding 0 or 1.

I have been searching for a solution for this and my searches have mostly came up with answers that are pointing to the direction to use a text editor. As I mentioned earlier, the problem with the text editors is not necessarily opening the file (UltraEdit for instance can handle for the most part a file of this size). It is manually inserting one attribute after more than 700,000 attributes, which is an extremely time consuming task.

So, I ask the community if what I need to do is possible using a command line argument (awk/grep, etc.) to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I know you said 'command line util', but is python installed on the system? It would be very easy in python.

Comment: You are right. I found the following code [HERE] http://margerytech.blogspot.it/2011/03/python-appending-column-to-end-of-tab.html and it solved the problem. I updated my question to include the possibility to use python. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is great because it's installed by default on a lot of POSIX-based systems :)

Now some caveats:

- this is simple python and intended for you to learn as you go, so it could be much more optimized
- this will read the entire file into memory while processing, so if your file is in the GB, it's going to hit your computer a bit
- I recommend throwing some `print` statements, or using the python debugger to step through the program if you want to know what's going on.

Here's what I came up with:

```py
lookup = {}
output_list = []

# build a lookup based on the lookup file
with open('lookup.csv', 'rb') as lookup_file:
    rows = lookup_file.readlines()

    for row in rows:
        key, value = row.split()
        lookup[key] = value

# loop through the big file and add the values
with open('input-big-data.txt', 'rb') as input_file:

    rows = input_file.readlines()
    target_zone = False

    for row in rows:

        # keep a copy of every row
        output_for_this_row = row

        # skip the normal attribute rows
        if row.startswith('@'):
            target_zone = False

        # check to see if we are in the 'target zone'
        if row.startswith('@data'):
            target_zone = True

        # start parsing the rows, but not if they have the attribute flag
        if target_zone and not row.startswith('@'):
            # do your data processing here
            # strip to clobber the newline, then break it into pieces
            row_list = row.strip().split(',')
            # grab the last item
            lookup_key = row_list[-1].strip()
            # grab the value for that last item
            row_list.append(lookup[lookup_key])
            # put the row back in it's original state
            output_for_this_row = ",".join(row_list) + "\n"

        output_list.append(output_for_this_row)


with open('output-big-data.txt', 'wb') as output_file:
    for line in output_list:
        output_file.write("{}".format(line))
```

I've commented pretty thoroughly throughout, so it should be pretty self-explanatory.

From the files in your question, I've named them in order: `input-big-data.txt`, `lookup.csv`, and `output-big-data.csv`.

Here's the output from my example:

```
@relation 'filename'
@attribute "place" string
@attribute "institution" string
@attribute "food" string
@attribute "book" string

@data
3.8,6,0,0,church,1
86.3,0,63.1,0,man,1
0,0,0,37,woman,0
```

Hth,
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

---

As commented below, python can solve this problem quite simply as demonstrated by the solution that I found and used on this blog: http://margerytech.blogspot.it/2011/03/python-appending-column-to-end-of-tab.html.

It is not a command line argument (as I indicated I wanted to use in the question), but it solves the problem all the same.